# Updating a cell with fixed format without using code, formulas only

Tags: google-sheets

I have cell A1 = `1,0,0,1` cell B1=`,1,,-1`

I need a formula that would be the equivalent of `=update(A1,B1)`.
The numbers between the commas can be any number. I need B1 to replace data in A1 where there is a number.

Cell C1 output: `1,1,0,-1`

Note: A1 and B1 will always be in that format, 4 numbers separated by commas.

more examples:

A1 = `1,0,0,1` cell B1=`,1,,-1` --> `1,1,0,-1`

A1 = `10,0,0,1` cell B1=`,1,,-1` --> `10,1,0,-1`

A1 = `10,0,0,01` cell B1=`,1,,-1` --> `10,1,0,-1`

A1 = `10,0,-1,0` cell B1=`,1,,-1` --> `10,1,-1,-1`

A1 = `10,1,0,1` cell B1=`,0,,-1` --> `10,0,0,-1`

A1 = `10,0,0,01` cell B1=`-1,1,,` --> `-1,1,0,01`

General:
A1 = `a,b,c,d` B1 = `e,f,g,h` --> make C1 by replacing `a` with `e`, `b` with `f`... etc, if `e,f,g,h` are not blanks.

Comment: "B1 to replace data in A1" - this is not possible and it would lead to #REF! circular dependency paradox

Comment: @user0. Sorry for being unclear... what about now? I think it's possible, just complicated. probably needs a `split` function and maybe `replace` and `if` along with `arrayformula` I just haven't figured it out yet. Someone really good could probably make use of the `regexreplace`.

Comment: could you provide a copy/sample of your sheet? (it would surely fasten up things)

Comment: is the output always same? what would be the output of different string then 1,0,0,1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this sample formula? I think that there are several answers to your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Sample formula:

For example, when "A1" and "B1" are `1,0,0,1` and `,1,,-1`, respectively. Please put this formula to "C1".

```
=JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
  ISBLANK(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1,"([-\d]+)","\'$1"),",",true,false)),
  SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([-\d]+)","\'$1"),",",true,false),
  SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1,"([-\d]+)","\'$1"),",",true,false)
)))
```

- Add `'` before a number. By this, for example, `01` can be used as `01`.
- Split the string in the cell.
- Compare each element.

  - If there is no value in "B1", the element of "A1" is used.
  - If there is a value in "B1", the element of "B1" is used.
- Join each element as a string value.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

If you want to use `01` as `1`, please use the following formula.

```
=JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
  ISBLANK(SPLIT(B1,",",true,false)),
  SPLIT(A1,",",true,false),
  SPLIT(B1,",",true,false)
)))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you edit the formula, so the last step is not `Join each element as a string value` but `Join as value`? I threw in `01` just to test the code. Now i realize it should be all values and not string.

Comment: @jason I'm really sorry for my incomplete answer. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @user0 Thank you for editing. I could study from your edit.

Comment: exactly what I needed. And really elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of ways how to get it. for example:

**`=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;1);1;1)&",1,"&INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;1);1;3)&RIGHT(B1;3);)`**

[image]

---

**other approaches:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;1);1;1)&","&
         INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;1);1;2)&","&
         INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;1);1;3)&
         RIGHT(B1;3);)
```

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;1);1;1)&LEFT(B1;1)&
         INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;1);1;2)&LEFT(B1;1)&
         INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;1);1;3)&
         RIGHT(B1;3);)
```

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;1);1;1)&LEFT(B1;1)&
         INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;1);1;2)&LEFT(B1;1)&
         INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;1);1;3)&
         INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;1);1;4);)
```

---

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(","; IF(INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;1)<>"";INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;1);
                                                       INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;0);1;1));
                   IF(INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;2)<>"";INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;2);
                                                       INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;0);1;2));
                   IF(INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;3)<>"";INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;3);
                                                       INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;0);1;3));
                   IF(INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;4)<>"";INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;4);
                                                       INDEX(SPLIT(A1;",";1;0);1;4)));)
```

---

## final formula:

---

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(","; 
 IF(INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;1)<>"";INDEX(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(B1;",";",'");",";1;0);1;1);
                                     INDEX(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";",'");",";1;0);1;1));
 IF(INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;2)<>"";INDEX(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(B1;",";",'");",";1;0);1;2);
                                     INDEX(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";",'");",";1;0);1;2));
 IF(INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;3)<>"";INDEX(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(B1;",";",'");",";1;0);1;3);
                                     INDEX(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";",'");",";1;0);1;3));
 IF(INDEX(SPLIT(B1;",";1;0);1;4)<>"";INDEX(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(B1;",";",'");",";1;0);1;4);
                                     INDEX(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";",'");",";1;0);1;4)));)
```

[image]

Comment: i don't understand. any of the numbers between the commas could be any number. not sure how a `if` statement with specific strings would help

Comment: @jason well, your question is too broad. try to edit it and add more data/examples

Comment: I see strings in it... i can't go through all of the combinations, but it has to be flexible so any of the data can be "updated"

Comment: @jason the last one from my answer is able to do everything you requested